# cloud9でtomcatを設定しているとpermission deniedエラーが発生し先に進めません。

Tags: tomcat, jsp

こんにちは。
会社でjspを使うことになりました。
cloud9でやってみようと思い設定していると、
下記エラー躓いてしまいました…

#### 前提・実現したいこと

cloud9でtomcatを使えるようにしたいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
bash: apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/bin/startup.sh: Permission denied
```

#### 該当のソースコード

コンソールに以下を打ち込む。

```
apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/bin/startup.sh
```

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
javac 1.8.0_111
```

ディレクトリ
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

‐‐ここまでの構築手順‐‐
●Tomcat
①tar.gz (pgp, md5, sha1)をPCのDownloadディレクトリにインストール
②同ディレクトリ内で解凍
③解凍されたファイルをCloud9のJavaディレクトリにコピー
④環境変数をこのようにcloud9内のコンソール内で設定。

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/ubuntu/ファイル名(ディレクトリ画像の黒塗り部分)/Java/jdk1.8.0_92
export CATALINA_HOME=/home/ubuntu/learning_grrovegear/java/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13
```

こちらも試しました。

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

⑤Tomcat を展開

```
①wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.4/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.4.tar.gz
②tar xzf apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13.tar.gz
```

それぞれコンソールからこう返ってきました。

```
①--2016-11-17 04:57:04--  http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.4/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.4.tar.gz
Resolving www-us.apache.org (www-us.apache.org)... 140.211.11.105
Connecting to www-us.apache.org (www-us.apache.org)|140.211.11.105|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-11-17 04:57:04 ERROR 404: Not Found.

②tar (child): apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar (child): At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

⑥Tomcatを起動

```
apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/bin/startup.sh
```

上記エラー内容につながります。

足りない情報があれば言ってください！
よろしくお願いします。

マルチポスト
teratail [cloud9でtomcatを設定しているとpermission deniedエラーが発生し先に進めません。](https://teratail.com/questions/55516?modal=q-comp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

普通にブラウザで見てみましたが404 Not Foundです。

http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.4/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.4.tar.gz

Comment: Yukihiro Hondaさん

ありがとうございます。
環境変数あたりに原因があるということでしょうか？

Comment: えっ。。。インストールするためにインストールパッケージ(？)をダウンロードしようとしているが、指定したファイルがないのです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認してみます。

Comment: 解決しました!
インストールしたパッケージ名をURLに反映していないのが原因でした。  
【間違ったURL】
`wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.4/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.4.tar.gz`　　
【正しいURL】
 `wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13`

Answer (score 0):

既に解決してるようですが・・・

8.5.4 は 古いバージョンなのでTomcatのサイトからはダウンロードできません。古いバージョンは http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/ から入手できます。

Comment: おお…そうなんですね。
参考にしたサイトがこの型を使っており、記事の投稿日も今年の7月でしたので気が付きませんでした((+_+))
ありがとうございます。